In Baba Is You, is it mathematically possible to determine whether a level is possible or not?
Inspired by this: 


This is a level pack containing intentionally impossible Baba Is You levels.
Now I'll bet there's probably some brute-force method for this that considers every possible move. But is there some algorithm to determine the possibility of a Baba Is You level?

Building on @quazmlpok's answer, and the comments on that answer:
Given sufficiently large (but not infinite) memory, you can make an algorithm that solves the halting problem for any Turing machine that itself has bounded memory. the trivial solution is to simply enumerate all possible states of the memory (here, all different combinations of all the possible blocks), and run the game for one step  times 5 for each of the actions you may perform. For each state, either it terminates (winning, dying, crashing, hard-crashing) or it transforms into another state that you by definition also solved. You can then build a graph of all states and identify which ones are part of a loop (never halts) and which ones are part of a chain that ends up halting.
I could not find an estimate for the total number of different blocks that may (or may not) be placed in a level, but it seems there are more than 100 Property blocks alone. Taking the worst-case scenario of 2048*2048-size levels, and assuming a reasonable 1 byte per square, you would need 2048^2^100^5 bytes, a number with 3312 digits. This is only for properties but the maths holds for larger finite numbers of different placeable things.
For context, this is A LOT more than there are atoms in the universe (I am struggling to express how much "number of atoms in Trillions of universes" does not even make a dent in that number), but from a pure maths standpoint, this very far from infinity. If you could somehow build a computer to store all these level states, then you could solve the halting problem for BIY.
This all assumes that BIY is deterministic (it is not: e.g. the Chill property, though you could also enumerate all possible resulting states from the random movements, since that is also a countable number), and it also doesn't take into account the fact that more than 1 thing may be occupying a square (through stacking).
I'm actually unsure on how to approach stacking, because it creates additional states that you cannot enumerate by simply placing something on squares, and as far as I know stacking can be infinite. if stacking can be infinite (disregarding Too Complex! and the like), then the game is probably truly Turing complete and its halting problem is undecidable. If stacking has a limit i'm not aware of, then the number of states would grow even more extremely large, but it would still be possible to enumerate all possible stacks on all possible squares, and solve the halting problem.
This is across all possible levels, therefore for a given level (that does not permit stacking, for simplicity), you can simply find the starting state of the level in the graph, and find a path of moves that gets it to win, or you don't and the level is impossible.

Baba is You is Turing complete, as demonstrated in this twitter post that implements Rule 110.
In practice this will run up against the 33x18 maximum level size, but according to reddit it's possible to use debug mode to get at least 2048x2048.
I'm not well versed enough in computer science to put this into any kind of real proof, but I believe the result of this is that knowing for certain if a level has a success state is equivalent to the halting problem, and therefore it is impossible.
I imagine it's also possible to do something similar to the passcode Mario Maker levels, where there is a solution but it's functionally impossible for another user to solve because they don't have the key.

I feel like the Halting Problem is not applicable here because there are a finite number of possible states of the board. At each state, you can do one of five inputs (Up Left Down Right Wait), and the results of those inputs are deterministic. Exhaustively searching the possibility space—even if that means trillions of nodes—will inevitably result in every state pointing to 5 other states that already exist in the decision tree. At that point, there either is or is not a "You Win!" state somewhere in the tree.

There's finite room on the board, but there's no limit timewise. I could be wrong, and I certainly can't prove anything, but I believe that's enough for the possibility space to be infinite.

@HitenStyle That's kind of the point, I think? "Will this halt / can this level be completed" is only answerable by... solving the level (which is what mapping all possible inputs does).

(Nit: Baba is You is not deterministic. There are several blocks that are explicitly random, although none of them are found in the official levels)

@qazmlpok that is not sufficient. All computational analysis assumes there is no time limit. As you cannot go back in time, you cannot use time to hold working information.

There's a BACK property. The wiki seems to imply that an object can have an arbitrarily long BACK stack, but I haven't tested, and the lack of random access could prove difficult.
